# How this for loop works in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Can someone explains to me how this output works like that spet by step? I know how a "for" loop and the "of" keyword works, at least I thought I knew, but this little snippet bellow just broke my legs.

```
for(let {x= 3, y = 2} of [{x: 1}, {y: 4}]) {
    console.log(`x: ${x}`);
    console.log(`y: ${y}`);
}
```

Output:

```
x: 1
y: 2
x: 3
y: 4
```

Comment: It is using default value when you are not sending any value for the variable

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters

Comment: That is called object destructuring, you can find a beautiful explanation from here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(let {x= 3, y = 2} of [{x: 1}, {y: 4}]) {
    console.log(`x: ${x}`);
    console.log(`y: ${y}`);
}
```

1. When the loop runs first time , x is passed as 1 and default value of y is used as 2 . It prints **x: 1 and y: 2**
2. Second time when loop runs , you pass y=4 and it takes default value x and prints **x:3 and y:4**